# change font color in pickerview

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I need to change the font colour in one row in my picker view, lets say it is my raven image,  how do I do that.
This is what I have so far.
I have searched but I am not finding the answer here.
And can I have a startup picture in my picker view app when i start it.

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
//Load up NSArray object
_fuglar = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Allt árið", @"Hrafn", @"Svartbakur",@"Silfurmáfur",@"Sílamáfur",@"Frá 20.ágúst til 15.mars",@"Grágæs",@"Heiðagæs",@"Frá 1.september til 15.mars",@"Fýll",@"Dílaskarfur",@"Toppskarfur",@"Helsingi",@"Stokkönd", @"Urtönd",@"Rauðhöfðaönd",@"Duggönd",@"Skúfönd",@"Hávella",@"Toppönd",@"Hvítmáfur",@"Hettumáfur",@"Rita",@"Álka",@"Langvía",@"Stuttnefja",@"Teista",@"Lundi",@"Rjúpa", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UIPickerView Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:      (NSInteger)component
{
return _fuglar.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [_fuglar objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
 //Create UIImage objects
UIImage * uglaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ugla1.jpg"];
UIImage * ravenImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"raven.jpg"];
UIImage * svartbakurImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"svartbakur2.jpg"];
UIImage * silfurmafurImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"silfurmafur.jpg"];


switch (row) {
    case 0:
        fuglarImage.image = uglaImage;
        break;
    case 1:
        fuglarImage.image = ravenImage;
        break;
    case 2:
        fuglarImage.image = svartbakurImage;
        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` instead of `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`.

Your implementation should return a `UILabel` with whatever attributes you need.

Comment: Ok thank you, could you maybe show me a sample code how I do this, I am new to programming and still learning :)